# How to find why semaphore is not locking

Tags: linux, ipc, deadlock, semaphore

I have a peculiar situation where couple of threads (actually 5 threads) hang. The reason is that it is waiting for a semaphore, and is not able to grab that.
ipcs -p doesnt show any tasks which has that semaphore.
ipcs -s -i shows a count of 5.

So, how do I know why the semaphore lock is not happening for these 5 threads ? How do I see if any thread is holding this semaphore.

(Analyzing the call stack, I couldnt see any task having the semaphore.)

Appreciate the help !

Comment: Are you checking for errors on every semaphore related system call? (semop, semget etc)  IIRC, EINTR errno and the signals associated with it have to be handled correctly or you can deadlock.  Used to be a frequent occurence for me in the early '00s with Informix + Tuxedo.

Comment: We are checking the return codes. But, this is legacy code, and I need to visit this code in detail to see any possible bugs

Answer (score 1):

I would write some debugging code around the use of the semaphores (i.e. before and after each all to those semaphore functions specifying which semaphore is being used and what thread). In addition I would double check to make sure that your code does not have any deadlocks. This is easy to achieve nu ensuring that you use the various semaphores in the same order for gaining the mutual exclusion lock and the reverse order for relieving the locks.

Apart from that the is very little help I can give you without the code.

Comment: This particular semaphore is used by 4 poller threads, and a main thread before HW access. So, this is kind of an endpoint to the call. So, no other sem/mutex calls come after this.

Comment: Also, since it's with 0.5 and 1 sec pollers, adding some prints is not feasible, and will throw off the timing because of which the issue will not happen.

Comment: Surely analyzin the call stack (as mentioned in the OP) throws off timing. How about writing something that emulates to some extent the HW where it is failing and just execute that part as a test case?